# trouble performing an advanced query between two tables

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the following tables:

1) t_products which includes a foreign key provider_id

2) t_provider whose primary key is provider_id

they ask me for the following:

Generate the code to obtain the provider with the ID “45636” together with the product it provides

my code is the following:

```
SELECT t_provider.name, t_provider.lastname, t_products.model, t_products.brand
FROM t_provider
  INNER JOIN t_products ON t_provider.id_provider = t_products.id_provider
WHERE provider_id = 45636
```

> ERROR 1052 Column "id_provider" in where clause is ambiguous

what i should get is a table like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3UZf.png)

Comment: It's good programming practice to qualify _all_ columns, at least when more than one table are involved. E.g. `tablename.columnname` instead of just `columnname`.

Comment: Do you have one column called `id_provider` and another called `provider_id`?  Confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the name of the referenced table to `provider_id`:

```
SELECT t_provider.name, t_provider.lastname, t_products.model, t_products.brand
FROM t_provider
  INNER JOIN t_products ON t_provider.id_provider = t_products.id_provider
WHERE t_provider.provider_id = 45636
```